# Supernovas create energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, astrophysics, supernova

Ok here we go. Supernovas do have to have energy spent to explode, that is known. That explosion power also equals to the energy spent to cause said explosion, this is also known . Besides creating those icky black holes that I am not going to talk about any longer, a supernova creates a large cloud of dust in its wake which is called a nebula. Ok you might say, why is a large cloud of dust so important, after all it is just dust. This dust is important because it will slowly accumulate. How so? well slowly and slowly (and I mean slowly) these dust particles smash together! This smashing really does create a small almost negligible amount of heat. This isn't important either? You are probably scratching you head right now and wondering, "Locomotive38, then what is actually important? I don't really care about all this unimportant stuff." Well I'll answer your question now. What is actually important is after small blobs of dust (excuse my terminology) accumulate, their gravity cause other blobs of dust to drift over and, eventually but inevitably, smash into the original blob of dust. Now that right there is free energy! Is this a violation of the conservation of energy?

Comment: Your logic doesn't require a supernova. Just take a rock and throw it upward. Then it falls back down and "*Now that right there is free energy!*"

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that, the rock doesn't come back to me because of my gravitational energy and I don't come to the rock because of gravitational energy, in fact the rock only goes to the earth because of the earth gravitational energy.

Comment: You keep asking about violations of conservation of energy, maybe instead you'd like to just  ask if there are examples of systems that violate energy conservation instead of just picking arbitrary examples.

Comment: ok "Are there examples of systems that violate energy conservation"

Comment: I mean you clearly can't just continue your question like that in the comments, I would just try again with a whole new question that asks for details about why we believe in conservation of energy and if there exist systems or theories that don't have energy conservation as a core tenant. So far as I can tell the misunderstanding is deeper than just does this specific example violate conservation

Comment: "*Are there examples of systems that violate energy conservation?*" - It depends on how exactly you define energy. Conceptually, energy conservation is a consequence of the Stationary Action Principle that always holds, so energy conservation is never violated. However, it is not always easy or even possible to define what exactly energy is. For this reason, especially in some cases in General Relativity, energy may be defined in such a way that it is not conserved. However, this doesn't imply "free energy". See this for example: https://vixra.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/energy-is-conserved/

Answer (score 4):

No, planet accretion doesn’t violate the conservation of energy, because Newtonian gravity is a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force). Any increase in kinetic energy comes from a decrease in gravitational potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the issue. Mass that is originally bound in the star that explodes has *negative* gravitational potential energy.

In order to allow this material (which becomes your dust) to escape, then sufficient kinetic energy has to be given to it to cancel out this negative potential energy. This energy is imparted to it in the supernova explosion. The source of that energy is that material that is closer to the centre of the original star collapses and its gravitational potential energy becomes even more negative.

Thus if we assume that the total energy of the bound supernova progenitor is initially negative (as it must be), then in order to allow some material to escape then the supernova remnant (black hole, neutron star etc.) must have an even more negative potential energy; especially as plenty of energy escapes in the form of neutrinos too.

Comment: Your explanation applies for type II supernovas, the more unusual type Ia and pair-instability ones are powered by nuclear fusion.

Comment: @KevinKostian the question talks about creating black holes. i.e. Type II supernovae.